# Assistance with Django model relationships

Tags: python, database, django, database-relations

```
    class Pinyin(models.Model):
    pinyinWord = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    englishWord = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    englishPhrase = models.TextField()
    pinyinPhrase = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s | %s" % (self.pinyinWord, self.englishWord)

class Learned(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s | %s | %s | %s" % (self.pinyinWord, self.user, self.date, self.learned) 
    pinyinWord = models.ForeignKey(Pinyin)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    learned = models.BooleanField()
```

I am new to django and programming for that matter and want to add a value from Model Pinyin to Model Learned but only if it has not already been added to learned for that specific user but can't seem to grasp exactly how to do this.

For example, I want to grab a value from Pinyin and if Pinyin.id and User.id are not already in Learned, then add the word to the Learned model with the user id, todays date and learned set to False/0.

Comment: It's going to be easier to help you if you can explain to us what you your are trying to represent in the real life because I don't have a clue.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. So Pinyin is chinese words using alphanumeric characters.  I want to add a pinyin word to the learned model but only if the user doesn't already have that word in the learned model.  The learned model is supposed to hold all pinyin words the person is learning and then when the person has learnt the word they click a button and it sets learned to True/1

Comment: I'll +1 jammon. If you want to make this transparent, use a manytomanyField and declare Learned as the 'throught' model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking:

```
uid = User.objects.get(username='Greg').id
pinyin = Pinyin.objects.get(pinyinWord='kuai')

learned, created = Learned.objects.get_or_create(pinyinWord=pinyin.pinyinWord, 
                                                                 user__id=uid)
if created:   # newly INSERTed Learned  instance
     learned.date = datetime.date.today()
     learned.learned = False
     learned.save()
```

The [**Model.objects.get_or_create**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method first tries a **Model.objects.get** call with the provided arguments. If it fails, the object will be created and *created* will be True, otherwise *created* is False.

Since this is an exact lookup (not pinyinWord__contains for example) for both fields, it will fail when there is no Learned instance that satisfies both fields. Then it gets created.

After that you can set the date and so on and save the instance.

Comment: I think this is more what I am looking for!  Gonna try a few things then get back to you.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the model meta option `unique_together`:

```
class Learned(models.Model):
    pinyinWord = models.ForeignKey(Pinyin)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    learned = models.BooleanField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'pinyinWord')
```